# CSS - Multiple images in one and using CSS to determine a background

Tags: css, trim

If you don't know what I mean, check this image out:

[Multiple images](http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/z3JQK/hash/11cngjg0.png)

I want to know how it works, CSS yes, but exactly how does it all work out when using a background using this image and then it is all cut all exactly what it is supposed to do - when determined as a background for this image.

Would be interesting for me to know how - so I can take my CSS level up a bit more :P

Thanks

Comment: I'd just like to say that this question should get more +1's because it's a CSS principle that every web developer should use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{
    height: foo;
    width: foo;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: colour url() no-repeat 0 pixels-to-top-of-image;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is [CSS Sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/), there are heaps of tutorials and ways to achieve this. Basically what you are doing is declaring a background and using `background-position` to decide what in the background is displayed.

CSS Sprites are great by the way, good job for trying to figure them out.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="buttonOne">Button 1</div>
<div id="buttonTwo">Button 2</div>

#buttonOne, #buttonTwo
{
    background-image: url(/images/ALL-BUTTONS-IN-ONE-IMAGE-TILED-16PX-APART.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#buttonOne
{
    background-position: 0 0;
}

#buttonTwo
{
    background-position: 0 -16px;
}
```